# Difference between getting Google profile picture via Google+ API and Google Profiles API?

Tags: google-workspace, google-plus, google-api

From what I can tell, Google provides two methods to get a profile picture.

The first is through the Profiles API:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/profiles/#retrieving_photo

The second is through the Google+ API:
https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people#image

My question is: What is the difference between these two methods? Are they simply different APIs, or could the two reply with different photos and/or in different circumstances (e.g. depending on your permissions)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Warning: The deprecation period for the Google Apps Profiles Data API is nearly at an end. On April 20, 2015, we will discontinue service for this API.

The main difference is the Google Apps Profiles API is getting shut down soon.